# Instagram API: how to catch access_token in Angular 2/4/5

Tags: javascript, angular, instagram-api

My angular 2 project is implementing the Instagram authentication as below:

1. Register Instagram Client, add sandbox user (as prerequisite)
2. In signup.html

   ```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-round"(click)="signInWithInsta()"><i class="fa fa-instagram"> Instagram </i> </button>
   ```
3. In signup.component.ts

   ```
   import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

   constructor(
           private router: Router,
           private route: ActivatedRoute   
       ) { }

   ngOnInit() {

      this.route
               .queryParams
               .subscribe(params => {
                   console.log('params: ' + JSON.stringify(params));
                   let at = params['#access_token'];
                   console.log('access_token: ' + at);
               });

   }

   signInWithInsta(): void {
           let url =
               'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=' + INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID +
               '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('https://localhost:4200/index.html#/access_token') +
               '&response_type=token';
           console.log(url);
           window.location.href = url;
       }
   ```

Result: 
the log I received is just empty.

Question: How to catch the access_token from Instagram API.

Any suggestion about implementing Instagram login in Angular 2/4/5 is also appreciated

Answer (score 1):

First, as per the notice by [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/developer/), the basic user details API will be deprecated in early 2020. So make sure you check out new API for Instagram login [here](https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/) and update your project.

For now, you can use below code to get access_token:

```
this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  // if instagram code exist on url parameters, then it's user logged in using instagram
  if (params.code) {
    this.authService
      .instagramGetUserDetails(params.code)
      .subscribe(() => {
        // clear the code param from URL
        this.router.navigate([], {
          queryParams: { code: null },
          queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
        });
      });
  } else if (params.error) {
    // if error returned by instagram
  }
});

// get Instagram user details and token
instagramGetUserDetails(code) {
  try {
    const body = new HttpParams()
      .set('client_id', environment.instagram_client_id)
      .set('client_secret', environment.instagram_client_secret)
      .set('grant_type', 'authorization_code')
      .set('redirect_uri', environment.instagram_redirect_uri)
      .set('code', code)
      .set('auth', 'no-auth');

    return this.http
      .post(environment.instagram_get_token_uri, body.toString(), {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
      })
      .pipe(
        tap(res => {
          // ----------->>>>>>   you get the token here   <<<<<---------------
          console.log(res.access_token)
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError<any>('instagram_auth'))
      );
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
}

// Handle error
private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
  return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
    // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
    console.error(error); // log to console instead

    // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
    console.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

    // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
    return of(result as T);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get queryParams using `const queryParams = this.route.snapshot.queryParams`
I came across the same situation, and your question was helpful!